# UITableView scrolling delay

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

### Found The solution with help of @parcs and @payal- This link helped -> http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Basically , the table view lags when i scroll, i have gone through many post but it didn't help-

[UITableView in UIScrollview scrolling delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932204/uitableview-in-uiscrollview-scrolling-delay)

[Delayed UIImageView Rendering in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826913/delayed-uiimageview-rendering-in-uitableview)

[slow scrolling of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410997/slow-scrolling-of-uitableview)

[UITableView lags while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286873/uitableview-lags-while-scrolling)

**This is the code , which i am using in cellForRowIndexpath**

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WorkoutCell";

        WorkoutCell *cell = (WorkoutCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(!cell)
        {
            UIViewController *controller=[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:CellIdentifier bundle:nil];
            cell=(WorkoutCell *)controller.view;
        }



        [[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [[cell backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        //diplaying Workout Data

        [cell setupFont];
        cell.lblPoint.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrTblData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"point"]];
        cell.lblReps.text=[[arrTblData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"reps"];
        cell.lblWorkoutCategory.text=[[arrTblData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"workout"];
        cell.lblWeight.text=[[arrTblData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"weight"];
        cell.lblSets.text=[[arrTblData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sets"];
        //Formatting Date
         cell.lblPostedDate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posted On: %@",[self formatDate:[[arrTblData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"time"]]];


        return cell;

    }
```

**The Function SetupFont called from cellForRowIndexpath**
    -

```
(void)setupFont
    {
        self.lblPoint.font=DEFAULT_FONT(13);
        self.pointLblScreen.font=DEFAULT_FONT(13);
        self.lblPostedDate.font=DEFAULT_FONT(13);
        self.lblReps.font=DEFAULT_FONT(13);
        self.lblSets.font=DEFAULT_FONT(13);
        self.lblWeight.font=DEFAULT_FONT(13);
        self.lblWorkoutCategory.font=DEFAULT_FONT(18);
        self.lblWorkoutCategory.strokeColor=kStrokeColor2;
        self.lblWorkoutCategory.strokeSize = kStrokeBigSize;
        for(UILabel *lbl in [self subviews])
        {


            if(lbl.tag==9)
            {
                lbl.font=DEFAULT_FONT(13);
            }

        }


    }
```

**Format Date Function called from cellForRowIndexpath**

```
#pragma mark - Format Date Function
-(NSMutableString*)formatDate:(NSString*)date
{
    NSMutableString *formattedDate=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    NSUInteger p = 0;
    NSUInteger length = [date length];
    while ( p < length) {
        unichar ch = [date characterAtIndex: p];
        if (ch!=' ')
        {
            if(ch=='-')
            {
                ch='/';
            }
            NSString *appendString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",ch];

            [formattedDate appendString:appendString];
            p++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return formattedDate;

}
```

Comment: The most unusual aspect of this code (and the probable cause of the problem) is allocating a view controller and then casting it's view as a tableviewcell.  You can learn a lot by commenting out all the other config steps, maybe just leave one line like this:  cell.lblPoint.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

Comment: why you assigning view controllers to the cell ,that is making your app slow..

Comment: @danh- Well, i have used this process in most of the app, but till now i didn't find this kind of problem before.

Comment: OK, I am checking it... i will let you all know.

Comment: @danh and Bullet Raja-- how can i replace this code           if(!cell)
        {
            UIViewController *controller=[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:CellIdentifier bundle:nil];
            cell=(WorkoutCell *)controller.view;
        }

Comment: This looks like a decent read.  The most relevant part is "Option 3" near the bottom...http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/

Comment: @danh- by Adding -> WorkoutCell *cell =(WorkoutCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; and in viewDidLoad-> static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WorkoutCell";
    //register Cell
    [self.tblWorkout registerClass:[WorkoutCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];                               This is giving Blank cell, means cell is not appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right way to do this:

```
WorkoutCell *cell = (WorkoutCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(!cell)
        {
            UIViewController *controller=[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:CellIdentifier bundle:nil];
            cell=(WorkoutCell *)controller.view;
        }
```

Instead of this, subclass `UITableViewCell` and instantiate that cell here as follows:

```
WorkoutCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WorkoutCell" owner:self options:nil]; 
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
```

Also, move your `setupFont` method the `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Comment: This is giving Blank cell, means cell is not appearing

Comment: Are you using xib? If yes then instantiate the cell using this: cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: in place of this statement: cell = [[WorkoutCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: an error mate-- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0xa558540> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

Comment: Have you made the @property in the UITableViewCell subclass? It would be good if you can post some code.

Comment: Thanks for the code snapshot, On which statement your code breaks?

Comment: in this line ---> cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"WorkoutCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Please use this instead and debug it and look at the array count. 
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WorkoutCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Your error indicates that you are setting the value to some key, that was not NSDictionary. Please share the implementation code of your WorkoutCell class.

Comment: meanwhile i am debugging as you said... u can check out the code http://pastie.org/8532649

Comment: *topLevelObjects contains this "<WorkoutCell: 0xa589420; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 411); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa589310>>"

Comment: Have you set the class of the xib to WorkoutCell? Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are typecasting the UIViewController to UITableviewCell.Instead of that take UITableViewCell class add the outlets whatever you want and use it

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

  CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {

  ```
  cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
  ```

  }

  // access that CustomCell variables here

  cell.name.text = @"Name";

}

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0xb2cb8a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

Comment: you have to subclass UITableviewCell and take an empty xib and add UItableviewcell and change the classname as your UItableviewCell class name and create outlets. that outlets you can use in your cellforRowAtIndex method

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
@interface WorkoutCell : UITableViewCell {}
```

then table view class

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString * const CellIdentifier = @"WorkoutCell";
WorkoutCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
if( !cell )
{
    cell = [[WorkoutCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
}
}
```

Comment: This is giving Blank cell, means cell is not appearing in uitableview

Comment: You see this example  http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: you didn't provided the link